# Net Core Moq - Persist Httpclient when running the same function multiple times within the same unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this unit test:

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "Http test")]
public async Task Http_Test_Should_Return_Something()
{
    var model = new Test();
    model.test1= "tt";
    var messageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

    messageHandler.ClientBuilder(url, delegate () { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model); });
    
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(messageHandler.Object, false);
    
     var func = new Class(httpClient, _propertiesSetOnContruct);
   
    //RUN FIRST TIME TO SET THE PRIVATE FIELDS AND DO THE NORMAL PROPERTY GATHERING
    await func.RunLogic();

    //RUN THE SECOND TIME TO GET THE DICT VALUE SET AND DONE AND RUN THE REST OF THE LOGIC
    await func.RunLogic();
}
```

This is my `ClientBuilder` Code in which I setup the handler to run the function:

```
public static void TokenClientBuilder(this Mock<HttpMessageHandler> handler, string requestUrl, Func<string> function)
{
    handler.Protected()
        .As<IHttpMessageHandlerMock>()
        .Setup(x => x.SendAsync(
            It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(r =>
                r.Method == HttpMethod.Post &&
                r.RequestUri == new Uri(requestUrl)),
            It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(function(),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json")
        });
}
```

So, to resume the code that I have there in the unit test, I basically need to cover all the code of the class that I am trying to check, the problem is that I need to run it 2 times within the same unit test, since the Dictionary that I want to populate can only be populated when I run the first time and the second check will only happen when the user goes again to the class.
Since the `Httpclient` is disposed when I go for the 2nd round I lose my content and I end up with a null value and when I try to do a Json Convert it obviously causes an exception.
I even thought of mocking the dictionary within the class, but it is private and I can't access it.

My question here is, is there any way, shape or form to mock the MessageHandler in order for the Httpclient to persist in the 2nd round of the unit test or do I need to do something else?

The code that I am trying to test is not relevant for here because it won't change and the constructor props and the props of the class are private, so nothing to do there.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: **Why** do you **think** you need to persist `HttpClient`?